# Inotify issues too many events on file move

Tags: c, inotify

I want to react on a certain file being moved into and out of a certain directory. The following code first watches for the file to be moved into the directory then watches for the same file to be moved out again.

```
unsigned char eventBuffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1];

int inotifyFd = inotify_init();

int watchFd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, "/home/root", IN_MOVED_TO);

for(;;) {
  unsigned offset = 0;
  int length = read(inotifyFd, eventBuffer, sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1);

  do {
    struct inotify_event *event = reinterpret_cast<struct inotify_event *>(eventBuffer + offset);

    if(event->mask & (IN_MOVED_TO)) {
      printf("File %s has been moved to /home/root/.\n", event->name);
      inotify_rm_watch(inotifyFd, watchFd);
      watchFd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, "/home/root/test.txt", IN_MOVE_SELF);
      if(watchFd < 0) {
        printf("Error: inotify_add_watch\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    } else if (event->mask & (IN_MOVE_SELF)) {
      printf("File /home/root/test.txt has been moved away.\n");
    }

    offset += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
    length -= sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
  } while(length > 0);
}
```

When I move the file test.txt into /home/root both events trigger immediately.

```
File test.txt has been moved to /home/root/.
File /home/root/test.txt has been moved away.
```

I don't understand this, because I install the `IN_MOVE_SELF` watch only after the `IN_MOVED_TO` event has triggered.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't develop or program as `root`. If you make a mistake (especially when it comes to file handling) it could lead to your system becoming corrupted and even totally bricked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am working on an embedded system.

Comment: That doesn't really matter. You should never run as a privileged user, not even on embedded systems. And I recommend development on a beefier host system, possible with cross-compilation for the target, and then copy the executable to the target system where it runs (as a non-privileged user).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am compiling with a cross-compiler on my host system. The real program I am working on is part of the update system, so it needs to run as root. The example I posted here would not need that. It was just convinient to use the /home/root directory, because it is one of a few directories that is not under control of ostree.